# Javascript template string placeholders

Tags: javascript, python

Is it possible to create a template string in javascript with placeholders to be filled in later, a la python?

for example, in python, I could do something like this:

```
def makeApiFunction(endpoint, requestFunction):

    def func(**params):
        return requestFunction(endpoint.format(**params))

    return func
```

and use it like so:

```
 someApiFunc = makeApiFunction('/api/v1/my/endpoint/{pk}/with/{random}/vars/', other_module.get)

 ### somewhere else
 someApiFunc(pk=1, random='some')
```

I suppose I could do something like this in javascript:

```
function makeApiFunction(endpoint) {
    return (params) => {
        Object.keys(params).map(key => {
           endpoint = endpoint.replace(`{${key}}`, params[key])
         })
 }
```

Is there a better way (something in-built I dont know about perhaps?)

Answer (score 1):

You should use external library for string templates. For instance you can take a look at [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#template)